# How to round only numbers in python dataframe columns with object mixed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding, numeric

[image]

I have a dataframe named "df" as the picture.
In this dataframe there are "null" as object(dtype) and numerics.
I wish to round(2) only the numeric values in multiple columns.
I have written this code but keep getting "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" as TypeError.
*The first line code is to convert na's to "null", since other numbers need to be numeric dtype.

```
df['skor_change_w_ts']=pd.to_numeric(df['skor_change_w_ts'], errors='coerce').fillna("null", downcast='infer')

for i in len(df):
    if df['skor_change_w_ts'][i] is float:
        df['skor_change_w_ts'][i]=df['skor_change_w_ts'][i].round(2)
```

What would be the most simple code to round(2) only numeric values in multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

`round` before `fillna`:

```
df['skor_change_w_ts'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['skor_change_w_ts'], errors='coerce')
                             .round(2).fillna("null", downcast='infer')
                          )
```

Example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'skor_change_w_ts': [1, 2.6666, 'null']})
```

Output:

```
  skor_change_w_ts
0              1.0
1             2.67
2             null
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call .fillna() at all, coerce will do that for you.

```
df['skor_change_w_ts'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['skor_change_w_ts'], errors='coerce').round(2)
```

Should do the trick.